# basic number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that for every integer $n\geq2$ there are two distinct powers of $n$ such that their sum is greater than $10^{2023}$ and their difference is divisible with $2023$

I tried to solve it but I'm sure I did something wrong.

Notes:

1. To prove the claim, we can use the pigeonhole principle.

   Let's consider the sequence of powers of $n$, i.e., $n^0, n^1, n^2, n^3, \ldots$.
2. Let $k$ represent the remainder when each power of $n$ is divided by $2023$. Since there are a finite number of remainders ($k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 2022$) and an infinite number of powers of $n$, by the pigeonhole principle, there must exist two distinct powers of $n$ with the same remainder, let's say $n^a$ and $n^b$.

   Now, we have $n^a \equiv n^b \pmod{2023}$, which implies $n^b- n^a \equiv 0 \pmod{2023}$. Note that $n^b- n^a$ is the difference between the two powers.

   To ensure that their sum is greater than $10^{2023}$, we need to find two powers of $n$ such that $n^a + n^b > 10^{2023}$.
3. Let's write the two powers of $n$ as $n^a$ and $n^{a+c}$, where $a < a + c$.
   Hence, $n^a + n^{a+c} > 10^{2023}\iff n^{a}(1+n^c) > 10^{2023}$.
   Now we have to find the smallest possible value of $n^c$ such that $n^c > 10^{2023}$ whose difference is divisible by $2023$.
   Taking the logarithm on the resultant inequality $c > 2023\log_{n}(10) $. This difference must be positive so we have $c\geq2024$, also $n^{2024} > 10^{2023}$. Taking $c$ as $2024$ satisfies the condition of the problem. The smallest value of $n$ that satisfies this condition is $\operatorname{lcm}(43,47)=2021$, so $n=2021$. Hence, the two largest powers of $n$ that satisfy these conditions are $2021^{2024}$ and $2021^{2\cdot2024}.$

Comment: What makes you "sure [you] did something wrong? I agree with your points1 and 2. Point 3 might be correct but I cannot follow it. Instead, I would write: once we have $a,c>0$ such that $2023\mid n^a(n^c-1),$ Simply let $N:= n^a(n^c+1)$ and choose $d$ large enough such that $n^d>10^{2023}/N.$ Then, $n^{d+a+c}$ and $n^{d+a}$ will do.

Comment: i was sure i did something wrong because im 15 and its the first time i tried to solve a fancy number theory problem and because im not that bright but apparently i did it right yay